# Determinant of a matrix with an unknown diagonal

Tags: matrices, determinant

In matrix $4 \times 4$ on the main diagonal I have elements $x + constant%$, where $x$ is real number. All other elements are the constans. How to prove that its determinant can be no-zero?

Comment: Do you mean $\pmatrix{x+c&c&c&c\\c&x+c&c&c\\c&c&x+c&c\\c&c&c&x+c}$?

Comment: What if $x$ and all the constants are $0$? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Yes. but all $c$ are different

Comment: The determinant is a polynomial in its entries. In terms of $x$, it is a polynomial of degree 4 with leading coefficients $1$. Since this is a non-zero polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, there is a $x$ with makes the polynomial non-zero. For this $x$, the determinant is non-zero. i.e the determinant "can be" non-zero.

Comment: If the "constants" form matrix $A$ with characteristic polynomial $q_A$, you are asking if $q_A (-x)$ can be nonzero, right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : For determinant zero, we must have any row (column) say ist row must be scalar multiple of others. As you mentioned x is only on diagonal, so you cannot able to find suitable scalars which combination forms ist row. So determinant is not zero.

Comment: need not be just a scalar multiple of another row or column, it could be a linear combination of columns (or rows).

Comment: What "ist" could mean?